# reference to a pointer vs reference to an int

Tags: c++, reference

When we create a *reference to an int*, we **cannot reassign** that reference to some other variable, like so:

```
int a = 100;
int a1 = 200;
int &b = a;
&b = a1; // will get an error
```

However, when we create a *reference to a pointer*, it seems that the reference to a pointer can be reassigned to some other pointer (the compiler doesn't check at compilation time) like so:

```
int main()
{
    int* p;
    int* p1;
    int t = 100;
    int t1 = 200;
    int*& ref = p;
    ref = &t;
    *&ref = p1;
    cout << p << endl;
    cout << *p << endl;
    cout << ref << endl;
    *&ref = p1;
    ref = &t1;
    cout << p1 << endl;
    cout << *p1 << endl; //segmentation fault
    cout << ref << endl; //segmentation fault.
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why doesn't the compiler check if we reassign the reference to a pointer to another pointer. Is this how the g++ is designed or am I missing some concept?

Comment: No. References cannot be re-bound. That's it. Unfortunately you have posted too much code to figure out why you think this may not apply to pointers.

Comment: You seem to mix up the meaning of `&` when used in a type and when used in an expression. In `&b = a1`, you're attempting to assign an `int` to a pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference between

```
*&ref = p1;
```

and

```
ref = p1;
```

Both copy the address from `p1`<sup>1</sup> into the pointer which is the target of the reference, neither mutate the reference.  And there is no longer a connection with `p1`, so writing `ref = &t1;` won't assign to `p1`.

In particular, `&ref` is equal to `&p`, because the reference is transparent.  All operators affect the pointed-to object, none affect the reference itself.

(subtle clarification, lambda capture-by-reference can actually capture the reference itself, not just the target object... but that's not an operator... and you can act on references themselves if they are contained inside structures, and you break type-safety while manipulating the parent structure, but attempting to overwrite the reference causes undefined behavior, all you can safely do is read from it)

<sup>1</sup> Since `p1` is uninitialized, making a copy of it is undefined behavior already.

Comment: okay, this makes a lot of sense. But what exactly do you mean by the reference being transparent?

Comment: @SeasonalShot: Transparent means the reference is invisible, you use its target using the same syntax that you would use that object by its original name.

Answer (score 3):

You are not reassigning the reference (which is impossible) but changing the value of the pointer the reference refers to.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is not "reassigning" the reference.

The reference is to a pointer.   Your code is changing the value of the pointer being referred to.   It is not changing the reference so it refers to a different pointer.

Try the statement

```
cout << p << ' ' << ref << endl;
```

And you see they both print the same address, since ref has been initialised to be a reference to p.    The value will naturally change whenever p or ref are assigned (e.g. "p = &some_variable" or "ref = &some_other_variable") but the two will always be in sync.

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentioned, you did not re-bound 'ref'.  You took the address pointed by the bound variable 'p' to point to 'p1', then had that point to t1.

p1 was and remained uninitialized, so cout << *p1 << endl is dereferencing and uninitialized value (and it just so happened to have an address out of your memory space).